# Cypress iterate through elements in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, automated-tests, cypress

I am struggling iterating through elements in an array using cypress/typescript.  I am logging everything great and able to see each index and what it shows but I am still returning the entire array vs the actual index and two days later I cannot figure out how to grab the actual index [0], [1], [2], etc.  I have a tried a lot of things but this is what I have as my latest try.  Thanks for any help ending my suffering!

```
    sportPage.getFirstCard().within(() => {
      sportPage.getSecondSection().within(() => {
        sportPage
          .getMyCoolType()
          .should('exist')
          .each(($item, $index) => {
            cy.wrap($item)
              .invoke('text')
              .then((text) => {
                if ($index !== 0) values.push(text);
                cy.log($index.toString());
                cy.log(text);
              });
          })
          .then(() => expect(values.toString()).to.equal('Yoga');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please fill in some gaps so don't have to make assumptions. Is `expect(values.toString())` the failure point and what does it have? What is the complete list of items? What does `.getMyCoolType()` do?

Comment: Correct, the expect is where it fails as it returns the entire array (all the same word, which is actually correct, and I want it to just return the each element one by one, not the whole thing.  the `.getMyCoolType()` which I changed or work purposes, just gets my that section in the DOM. expected 'Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ,Yoga ' to equal 'Yoga'

Comment: Ok, understood. So, `.each()` will iterate all the elements, and inside that you are pushing all texts to `values` array. At the end of the loop you enter `then()` at which point `values` will have that concatenation of texts. Do you want to do the `expect()` on individual items? If so, do it in the `.each()` loop.

Comment: Or you could change the `expect()` to use [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), like `expect(values.every(item => item === 'Yoga')).to.equal(true)`.

Comment: Thanks. I do want to do the `expect()` on individual items, yup. I did a super fast test and moved it up inside the `each` and it complained about `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'number'.`. Need to see what that is about. BTW, total non programmer here so that is why I'm struggling. I did this `if ($index !== 0) values.push(text).then(() => expect(values.toString()).to.eq('Yoga'));`

Comment: Just move the `expect()` by itself (and ditch the `.then()`) - using `if (index !== 0) expect(text.trim()).to.equal('Yoga')`. Threw in `.trim()` incase there's some spaces which you don't care about.

Comment: I'll post to an answer to be easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test the individual texts in the array of elements returned by `.getMyCoolType()`,

```js
sportPage.getFirstCard().within(() => {
  sportPage.getSecondSection().within(() => {
    sportPage
      .getMyCoolType()
      .should('exist')
      .each(($item, $index) => {
        cy.wrap($item)
          .invoke('text')
          .then((text) => {
            cy.log($index.toString());
            cy.log(text);
            if ($index !== 0) {
              expect(text.trim()).to.equal('Yoga');
            }
          });
      })
  });
});
```

Or to test all items after the loop

```
sportPage.getFirstCard().within(() => {
  sportPage.getSecondSection().within(() => {
    sportPage
      .getMyCoolType()
      .should('exist')
      .each(($item, $index) => {
        cy.wrap($item)
          .invoke('text')
          .then((text) => {
            if ($index !== 0) values.push(text);
            cy.log($index.toString());
            cy.log(text);
          });
      })
      .then(() => expect(values.every(item => item === 'Yoga')).to.equal(true) );
  });
});
```

You might also get away with this

```
sportPage.getFirstCard().within(() => {
  sportPage.getSecondSection().within(() => {
    sportPage
      .getMyCoolType()
      .should('exist')
      .then(($items) => {
        const texts = [...$items].map(item => item.text()); // map elements into texts
        return texts.slice(1);                              // ignoring the first one
      })
      .then((items) => expect(items.every(item => item === 'Yoga')).to.equal(true) );
  });
});
```